# Can't use the same controller for different html elements

Tags: angularjs, controller, angularjs-service, angularjs-controller

Hello every body I have a controller:

```
app.controller('CartController', ['$scope', 'cartDataService', function($scope, cartDataService){
    $scope.goodsCount = cartDataService.goodsCount;
    $scope.changeQuantity = function (quantity, id) {
        if (quantity < 1) {
            ngCart.removeItem(id);
        } else {
            ngCart.getItemById(id).setQuantity(quantity);
        }
        console.log(ngCart.getTotalItems());
        $scope.goodsCount = cartDataService.goodsCount;
    }
}]);
```

And service:

```
app.service( 'cartDataService', [ '$rootScope', 'ngCart', function( $rootScope, ngCart ) {
    return {
        goodsCount: ngCart.getTotalItems()
    };
}]);
```

(ngCart is a module, it stores goods in web storage)

And my view on the top of the page:

```
<div ng-controller="CartController" class="numerik"><% goodsCount %></div>
```

And view in body of the page:

```
<div ng-controller="CartController"><% goodsCount %></div>
```

When I'm calling `changeQuantity` method, data into the both views doesn't changes. What am I doing wrong, or maybe here I should use other logic?

Answer (score 0):

Angular services are `singleton`. So when you call your `cartDataService` it is instantiated and set the value `goodsCount` what `ngCart.getTotalItems()` returns, initially it maybe `undefined` or something.

Next time when you want the updated value from `cartDataService.goodsCount` it returns initial value **Not the changed value**

To get updated value you have to set the function and call the function later in your controller like

In service

```
return {
        goodsCount: ngCart.getTotalItems; // pass the function Not executed result. ngCart.getTotalItems() it returns executed result
    };
```

And in controller inside `$scope.changeQuantity` function

```
$scope.goodsCount = cartDataService.goodsCount(); //call the function here
```